# Angular2/4 post method not working

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, angular2-services, angular4-forms, angular4-httpclient

**I am new in angular2/ 4 web api. I want to save some data to database using angular 4 web api http. When i call a GET method from angular it works fine, but not working on POST method. I am getting 415 Unsupported Media Type.All the time, but when I use postman the post method is work fine because I change the content type to application/json.  when i use alert button i get [object,Object],But in angular2/4 it's not working... I see lots of issues with the same problem, but they don't work for me.**

**This is my service.ts file**

```
 CatchStockDetail(stock: any)
    : Observable<IStockdetails[]> {
    alert(stock);      

          let stockdetail = JSON.stringify([{ stock }]);
     let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
     let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this._http.post('http://localhost:1234/api/NewStockCount/' + 'Stock', stockdetail,
        { params: [{ stock }] })
        //  .map(res => res.json());
        //     .map(res => res.json().stock)
        .map((response: Response) => <IStockdetails[]>response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

**This is my component.ts file**

```
 this._enqService.CatchStockDetail(this.stock)
            .subscribe(value => {
                value.forEach(stock => {
                    this.stockdetail.push(this.stock)
                });
            },
                error => {
                    console.error(error);
                    this.statusMessage = "Problem with the service.Please try again after sometime";
                });
```

**This is my api code**

```
 [HttpPost]
    public void Stock([FromBody] List<spGetNewStockCountDetails_Result> jsonvalues)

    {
        foreach (spGetNewStockCountDetails_Result Datastock in jsonvalues)
        {
            spGetNewStockCountDetails_Result Stockobject = new spGetNewStockCountDetails_Result();
            Stockobject.schid = Datastock.schid;
            Stockobject.itemid = Datastock.itemid;
            Stockobject.itemcode = Datastock.itemcode;
            Stockobject.itemdescription = Datastock.itemdescription;
            Stockobject.packingtypeid = Datastock.packingtypeid;
            Stockobject.count = Datastock.count;

            enqentities.spGetNewStockCountDetails(Datastock.schid, Datastock.itemid, Datastock.itemcode, Datastock.itemdescription, Datastock.packingtypeid, Datastock.count);
        }

    }

    public class spGetNewStockCountDetails
    {

        public int schid { get; set; }
        // public int id { get; set; }
        public int itemid { get; set; }
        public string itemcode { get; set; }
        public string itemdescription { get; set; }
        public int packingtypeid { get; set; }
        public int count { get; set; }

    }
```

This is my error

"{"Message":"The request entity's media type 'text/plain' is not supported for this resource.","ExceptionMessage":"No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171962/discussion-on-question-by-brock-james-angular2-4-post-method-not-working).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your api is expecting an **array** but you send a **string** instead, that is why you get a status code of 415

And remove the param, it is not even required in your api.

```
CatchStockDetail(stock: any)
    : Observable<IStockdetails[]> {
    alert(stock);      

     let stockdetail = stock;
     let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
     let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
     return this._http.post('http://localhost:1234/api/NewStockCount/' + 'Stock', stockdetail, options)
        .map((response: Response) => <IStockdetails[]>response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

About the error you're encountering, look at your api, you're not even returning a data, which why on `map` you get an error, remove the `map` will solve your issue for now.

You have to update your component

```
this._enqService.CatchStockDetail(this.stock)
            .subscribe(value => {
if(typeof value !== 'undefined' && value != null){
         value.forEach(stock => {
              this.stockdetail.push(this.stock)
         });
     }
},
error => {
         console.error(error);
         this.statusMessage = "Problem with the service.Please try again after sometime";
});
```

Comment: i got this error OPTIONS http://localhost:1234/api/NewStockCount/Stock 0 ()

Comment: try my updated post, i added the headers in the request

Comment: i got the daatas on DB But i got some error in console

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: errors.ts:42 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of null
    at SafeSubscriber.eval [as _next] (NewStockCount.component.ts:124)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.ts:238)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:190)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.ts:135)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:95)
    at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.ts:135)
    at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:95)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.ts:80)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:95)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (xhr_backend.ts:104)

Comment: @JohnVelasquez the issue is his API, angular is expecting a result set of array, but his API return void.

Comment: @JohnVelasquez there is a problem i faced?

Comment: @JohnVelasquez i pass alist of datas to db when i send one or more data to db is save only one data. that is my problm i want to save a list of data to DB

Comment: is your `this.stock` an array or an object?

Comment: @JohnVelasquez array

Comment: I changed the `let stockdetail = [stock];` to `let stockdetail = stock;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172031/discussion-between-brock-james-and-john-velasquez).

Comment: @JohnVelasquez i got error POST http://localhost:1234/api/NewStockCount/Stock 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code:

```
 CatchStockDetail(stock: any): Observable<IStockdetails[]> {
    let body = JSON.stringify([stock]);
    let url = 'http://localhost:1234/api/NewStockCount/' + 'Stock';
    let head: Headers = new Headers();
    head.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    head.set('Accept', 'application/json');

    return this._http.post(url, body, head)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
CatchStockDetail(stock: any): Observable<IStockdetails[]> {   

    let stockdetail = JSON.stringify([{ stock }]);
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, params: [{ stock }]  });

    return this._http.post('http://localhost:1234/api/NewStockCount/' + 'Stock', stockdetail, options)
    .map((response: Response) => <IStockdetails[]>response.json())
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Noticed you are using the deprecated version of HTTP, from `@angular/http`. You should consider changing it to use `HttpClient` instead from `@angular/common/http` see: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient

Comment: @BrockJames, then the code is working at least on the angular side. Now the issue is on your server side, which is a separate question than this.