# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web API throwing 500 error and not allowing access on http post

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I've set up my Cors policy in my Startup.cs by first adding the policy to ConfigureServices method:

```
 services.AddCors(
            cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddPolicy("MyPolicy",
                    bldr => {  
                bldr.AllowAnyHeader()
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .WithOrigins("http://localhost:8001"); });

                cfg.AddPolicy("AnyGET",
                    bldr => { bldr.AllowAnyHeader().WithMethods("GET").AllowAnyOrigin();});
            });
```

And next I'm using this policy as declared in my Configure method:

```
            app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
            app.UseAuthentication();

           app.UseMvc(config => { config.MapRoute("MyAPIRoute", 
              "api/{controller}/{action}"); });
```

In My Controller I've Enabled Cors specifying my policy and I've configured a specific Controller method to accept a bearer token as as way authenticating a the http post:

```
namespace My.Api.Controllers
{
[EnableCors("MyPolicy")]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
```

....

```
 [HttpPost]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ChangePassword([FromBody] PasswordChangeViewModel model)
    {
```

From my angular app I am making a http post request to this method:

```
public changePassword(password: Password) {

return this.http.post("http://localhost:8000/api/account/changepassword", password,
  {
    headers: new Headers({"Authorization": "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem('token').toString()})
  }).pipe(map((res: Response) => res.json()));
}
```

I've tried every suggestion on stack overflow but nothing seems to work and continue to get this error:

[image]

I have the same setup for another project and this wasn't ever an issue. The only difference is I updated this angular app to the angular 6 from 5. Also whenever I make this call from Postman its successful. I've hit a wall and need help! Thanks in advance!

***UPDATE***
I've changed the angular call to:

```
public changePassword(password: Password) {

let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token').toString() });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

return this.http.post("http://localhost:8000/api/account/changepassword", password, options);
}
```

I'm still getting the same error.

***UPDATE***
I have also tried to change how my angular service makes the http post by using HttpClient from @angular/common/http:

```
public changePassword(password: Password) {

let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token').toString() });


return this.httpClient.post("http://localhost:8000/api/account/changepassword", password, { headers: headers} );
}
```

**UPDATE**
I'm going in circles with this. It seems like I've tried EVERYTHING. Please help!!

Comment: please reffer this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50576483/angular2-4-post-method-not-working

Comment: i think your problem is in angular side

Comment: @BrockJames thank you for your reply. I've updated the angular function above but I'm still getting the same error...

Comment: is your api working from postman?

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier yes it works from postman

Comment: @Rob This is the port number of my web application

Comment: the error should be in API logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured this out yesterday smh...I'm ashamed but the issue was that one of my Password model properties didn't match the ModelView Password in my API. Once they matched this worked fine...